# .htaccess is reloading some files twice

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is a custom made PHP website. I recently made it SEO friendly by copying the .htaccess file from wordpress and modify it a little. The problem is that some pages are realoaded twice especialy pages that have more than 1 backslash like download/something/ . I have noticed this when tracking pageviews one pageviews is counted as twice and i've done a lot of research regarding this and the pageviews are working good it's a very simple function that inserts a new row each time you view a page.

Things to keep in mind:

1. My website is inside some folders 'https://localhost/simbyone/sim/index.php'.
2. I don't want to use any GET variables i will have my variables from the URL string
3. I want .htaccess to look for existing directories located inside 'https://localhost/simbyone/sim/' and if it doesn't find any open index.php with all the strings attached something like 'localhost/simbyone/sim/blabla/' but inside index.php
4. everything works exactly as i said above the only thing that doesn't do right is that it double loads some pages
5. this is my .htaccess file:

```
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /simbyone/sim/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /simbyone/sim/index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the .htaccess inside your base folder (in your case, simbyone/sim).

Just put this in the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php
```

This will rewrite and request that is not an existing file or folder to the index.php file.
There you can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to evalute the request (keep in mind that the prefix "/simbyone/sim/" will be present there.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. I have an empty index with only insert a row to database.

- When i visits /simbyone/sim/ it inserts 1 row
- When i visits /simbyone/sim/download/asd/ it inserts 2 rows

This is happening using your settings :(

Comment: I also noticed that it works correctly on internet explorer but not on chrome so meybe this is something browser related.

Comment: @Popa Robert Well, that is strange. I use this htaccess for multiple projects and it never failed. Try to store $_SERVER array to an external log and try to see if it adds 2 log enteries for a single request and check the request uri for both enteries if it does.